# kotlin return type of nullable?.let{}

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, nullable, return-type

I'm new to Kotlin and i'm playing a bit with android studio from few days. This is the class i'm dealing with:

```
class MyDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setMessage(R.string.exit)
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive) { _: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw Exception("problem detected with throw Exception on creating Dialog")

    }

}
```

I'm not understanding what is returning

```
return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setMessage(R.string.exit)
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive) { _: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw Exception("problem detected with throw Exception on creating Dialog")
```

I know the fun onCreateDialog returns a "Dialog" object because

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog
```

is returning a Dialog type (the code works in fact), but i don't understand how the "return" works in that case, am i returning all the brackets content? Thx everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` returns the result of last expression inside it, in this case the value of `builder.create()`, a non-nullable AlertDialog.

Since you use `?.let`, if `activity` is null, `let` won't be called, and you will effectively have `null ?: throw...`.

`builder.create()` never returns null, so this `throw` expression is only reached when `activity` is null, so the error message doesn't make sense.

Comment: One more thing, `onCreateDialog()` won't be called unless currently attached to an activity, so the whole `?.let` can be stripped away and `AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())` can be used instead.